# How to preserve chart formatting and textbox in existing excel files using Openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, excel, charts, format, openpyxl

I am using Openpyxl to add some data to an existing excel file but unfortunately it also changes the format of my chart (border, background and curves colors) and deletes textbox.

Does anyone know how to prevent these changes ?
Thanks ahead !

A simplified version of my code below and
[a screenshot of my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuDMn.jpg)
so everyone can reproduce the excel file.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

folder = r'C:\MyFolder'
filename = r'test.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(folder, filename),
    engine='openpyxl',
    datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy')

writer.book = load_workbook(os.path.join(folder, filename))
writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

writer.save()
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to do everything in openpyxl where you can interact with the charts. Textboxes are not supported.

Comment: Thank you @CharlieClark for your answer !